# ckeditor how to submit when it completes loading

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ckeditor

Hi There I am using CKEditor in one of my applications.

Is there a way that I can submit a form once the ckeditor has loaded.

```
 {
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'g_content_text' );
        toolbar : 'Basic'
  CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',
      function( evt )
      {
         var editor = evt.editor;
         editor.execCommand('maximize');
      });
    };
```

I have the

```
{
  document.form1.submit();
}
```

but it submits the form before the ckeditor has finished loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried putting after the `editor.execCommand('maximize');` ? It seems to be called once the instance is ready.

```
  CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',
      function( evt )
      {
         var editor = evt.editor;
         editor.execCommand('maximize');
         document.form1.submit();
      });
    };
```